# Re sizable and Movable Circle

Tags: c#, drawing

I create a code give that allow me to resize a circle and move it

1. first mouse click give me the center for the circle.
2. the circle radius will change with the cursor movement (closer to the center smaller radius farther from the center bigger radius).
3. click second time the radius will not be changed and the circle will be finalized.

This is an image similar to what I want to do:

http://lh6.ggpht.com/_wQH6U92SY04/S_6lAJI7E-I/AAAAAAAAKwE/i-Jkq-nI5Ss/GoogleMapCircle%5B11%5D.gif?imgmax=800

The problems are :

1. the center is not exactly where I click the mouse first time.
2. the cursor should be exactly at the circle border when I move it.
3. the biggest problem is after clicking second time the circle is move farther from the center .

PLEASE HELP

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace project
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
    }



    Bitmap background;
    Graphics scG;
    Rectangle rectangleObj;
    int clikno = 0;
    private Point clickCurrent = Point.Empty;
    private Point clickPrev = Point.Empty;



    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        background = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
        rectangleObj = new Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 100);
        scG = Graphics.FromImage(background);

    }

    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        clickCurrent = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
       clickPrev = clickCurrent;
        rectangleObj.X = e.X;
        rectangleObj.Y = e.Y;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        pe.Graphics.DrawImage(Draw(), 0, 0);

    }


    public Bitmap Draw()
    {
        Graphics scG = Graphics.FromImage(background);
        Pen myPen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red, 3);
        scG.Clear(SystemColors.Control);
        scG.DrawEllipse(myPen, rectangleObj);
        return background;

    }

    protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseClick(e);
        clikno = clikno + 1;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
       double oradius = Math.Sqrt((Math.Pow(clickPrev.X - e.X, 2)) + (Math.Pow(clickPrev.Y - e.Y, 2)));
       int radius = Convert.ToInt32(oradius);

        if (clikno == 1)
        {

                rectangleObj.Height = radius;
                rectangleObj.Width = radius;
            rectangleObj.X = clickPrev.X; 
            rectangleObj.Y = clickPrev.Y; 
            Refresh();
        }
        if (clikno == 2)
            clikno = 0;
        Refresh();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Try putting the code in `Form1_MouseDown` into `OnMouseClick`. They are different events.

Comment: How do you plan to let the user abort/clear the first Click?

Comment: Thank you for trying help..I figured it out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Project
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
    }

    Bitmap background;
    Graphics scG;
    Rectangle rectangleObj;
    Rectangle center;

    int clikno = 0;
    private Point clickCurrent = Point.Empty;
    private Point clickPrev = Point.Empty;



    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        background = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);//, this.Width,this.Height);
        rectangleObj = new Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 100);
        center = new Rectangle(10, 10, 3, 3);
        scG = Graphics.FromImage(background);

    }

    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        clickCurrent = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        clickPrev = clickCurrent;
        if (clickPrev == Point.Empty) return;
        Refresh();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        pe.Graphics.DrawImage(Draw(), 0, 0);

    }


    public Bitmap Draw()
    {
        Graphics scG = Graphics.FromImage(background);
        Pen myPen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red, 3);
        scG.Clear(SystemColors.Control);
        scG.DrawEllipse(myPen, rectangleObj);
      //  scG.DrawRectangle(myPen, rectangleObj);
        scG.DrawEllipse(myPen, center);

        return background;

    }

    protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseClick(e);
        clikno = clikno + 1;
    }






    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
       double oradius = Math.Sqrt((Math.Pow(clickPrev.X - e.X, 2)) + (Math.Pow(clickPrev.Y - e.Y, 2)));
     int radius = Convert.ToInt32(oradius);

        if (clikno == 1)
        {

           rectangleObj.Height = radius;
           rectangleObj.Width = radius;
            rectangleObj.X = clickPrev.X- rectangleObj.Height /2;// +radius; 
            rectangleObj.Y = clickPrev.Y - rectangleObj.Width / 2;// +radius; 
            center.X = clickPrev.X - center.Height / 2;// +radius; 
            center.Y = clickPrev.Y - center.Width / 2;// +radius; 
            Refresh();
        }
        if (clikno == 2)
            clikno = 0;
        Refresh();
    }
    string myString = 5.ToString();

}
```

}